# How to change the value of the key form an object with the value of some another key of the same object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a json object like this:

```
    {
       "id":"cfab8e92-025a-4070-ba1f-5bb1a8b3c9b6",
       "custome-array":[
          {
             "date1":"12/10/2019",
             "date2":"12/09/2019",
             "id":"cfab8e92-025a-4070-ba1f-5bb1a8b3c9b6",
             "more_data":{
                "id":"59c12dbf1d41c818272198b3",
                "some_no":"9204506",
                "name":"blabla"
             }
          },
          {
             "date1":"12/10/2019",
             "date2":"12/09/2019",
             "id":"cfab8e92-025a-4070-ba1f-5bb1a8b3c9b6",
             "more_data":{
                "id":"59c12dbf1d41c818272198b3",
                "some_no":"9204506",
                "name":"blabla"
             }
          }


  ]
}
```

My "custome-array" is dynamic

I want to use the map function to modify this data format so that "more_data" will only store "name" rather than storing the complete object.

```
{
       "id":"cfab8e92-025a-4070-ba1f-5bb1a8b3c9b6",
       "custome-array":[
          {
             "date1":"12/10/2019",
             "date2":"12/09/2019",
             "id":"cfab8e92-025a-4070-ba1f-5bb1a8b3c9b6",
             "more_data":"blabla"

          },
          {
             "date1":"12/10/2019",
             "date2":"12/09/2019",
             "id":"cfab8e92-025a-4070-ba1f-5bb1a8b3c9b6",
             "more_data":"blabla"

          }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried. A simple `for` or `forEach` should solve this

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any problems/errors with your approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with simple [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) loop.You can mutate the original array,with `forEach's` callback.

```js
let data = {
  "id": "cfab8e92-025a-4070-ba1f-5bb1a8b3c9b6",
  "custome-array": [{
      "date1": "12/10/2019",
      "date2": "12/09/2019",
      "id": "cfab8e92-025a-4070-ba1f-5bb1a8b3c9b6",
      "more_data": {
        "id": "59c12dbf1d41c818272198b3",
        "some_no": "9204506",
        "name": "blabla"
      }
    },
    {
      "date1": "12/10/2019",
      "date2": "12/09/2019",
      "id": "cfab8e92-025a-4070-ba1f-5bb1a8b3c9b6",
      "more_data": {
        "id": "59c12dbf1d41c818272198b3",
        "some_no": "9204506",
        "name": "blabla"
      }
    }


  ]
}

data["custome-array"].forEach(ele => {
  ele["more_data"] = ele["more_data"].name;
})
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use map:

```
const newItems = originalObject["custome-array"].map((item) => {
    const newItem = item;
    newItem.more_data = item.more_data.name;
    return newItem;
});

const newObject = {
    ...originalObject,
    ["custome-array"]: newItems
};

console.log(newObject);// this will give you the output you want
```

I've added a codepen to demonstrate https://codepen.io/csteur/pen/vqZLNK

Comment: There is no point in using `map` if you're mutating the original array

Comment: This is just to demonstrate map.

Answer (score 0):

```js
yourObject["custom-array"] = yourObject["custom-array"].map((item) => {
    return {
        ...item,
        ["more_data"]: item["more_data"]["name"],
    }
});
```

or

```js
yourObject["custom-array"] = yourObject["custom-array"].map((item) => ({
        ...item,
        ["more_data"]: item["more_data"]["name"],
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mutate the original data

```
const transformedData = {
  id: data.id,
  'custome-array': data['custome-array'].map(item => ({
    ...item,
    more_data: item.more_data.name,
  })),
};
```